# resize iframe (appetize.io) when content changed (cross domain)

Tags: html, css, iframe, resize

I'm trying to automatically resize an iframe that embeds the content of another website. I haven't been able to find a solution yet, so I need your expertise !

The problem: I embed the content of a mobile-like display (appetize.io) in an iframe on my site.
I do have buttons to rotate and change the size of the mobile.
But when I do that, the size of the iframe is not adapted accordingly. As a result, the display of the mobile is truncated.
I'd like to automatically resize the iframe.

**HTML:**

```
Device orientation: <button onclick="rotateLeft()">rotate left</button>
<button onclick="rotateRight()">rotate right</button><br/>
Device size:  <button onclick="setScale(10)">small</button> <button onclick="setScale(75)">normal</button>
<button onclick="setScale(100)">big</button>
<br/>
<iframe id="iframeid" scrolling="no" src="https://appetize.io/embed/demo_phq04c56jnvrkg0bn9w5ep4m9r?device=iphone8&orientation=portrait&scale=75&xdocMsg=true&deviceColor=white&debug=true&screenOnly=false"></iframe>
```

**For the javascript and css, see the fiddle directly: http://jsfiddle.net/f5u9mh8s/**

Try clicking on the resize and rotate buttons, and you will see...

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A clean and simple solution exists because you are using Appetize, which has an API available to you for this very purpose. If the iframe contained another site without an API to tell you the device orientation, the solution would become less reliable.

Once you have launched an Appetize session in the iframe, you can receive messages via the Appetize API. The [Appetize docs](https://appetize.io/docs#cross-document-messages) indicate than an `orientationChanged` message will be posted to the parent when the device is rotated. They helpfully provide [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/appetize/f97hs3ru/) in which you can test this. Open up the browser console, and after you click the Tap to Play button, when you rotate the device using the rotate right or left buttons you will see a message logged in the console, saying whether the device is portrait or landscape.

This means you can listen for messages from the iframe, and when you receive an `orientationChanged` message you can resize your iframe accordingly.

For example (this is just adapting code from the Appetize fiddle):

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('iframeid');

var messageEventHandler = function(event){
    if(event.data && event.data.type == 'orientationChanged'){
        if (event.data.data == 'landscape') {
            iframe.height = '416px';
            iframe.width = '870px';
        } else if (event.data.data == 'portrait') {
            iframe.height = '870px';
            iframe.width = '416px';
        }
    }
};

window.addEventListener('message', messageEventHandler, false);
```

Comment: Hi Jla,

Thank you so much for your quick answer!
I just had to do a little change and it worked like a charm: replace 
`"event.data.data == 'landscape'" `
by
`event.data.value == 'landscape'`
and same for `event.data.value == 'portrait'`

Comment: @LaurentWiart no worries, glad to have helped. If an answer has solved your problem please mark it as accepted.